# What did Kady's note to Penny say?

Tags: the-magicians, sy-fy

In SyFy's *The Magicians* season 1 episode 7 ("The Mayakovsky Circumstance" - the one where they're in a cold place with a guy with a very fake Russian accent), towards the end of the episode, Kady leaves a note for Penny. When he reads it, Penny does the "show it to the audience" thing, but nevertheless, I couldn't read the writing. Are we supposed to know what the note said? If yes, what did it say?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kady's note said: "Forgive me"

[image]

Comment: Well, that answer is kind of definitive, innit? :) Thanks muchly!